# GetTcpTable doesn't work like netstat

Tags: c++, winsock

In my winsock application i call **bind** on some port. I am testing now, so application crashes very often and doesn't reach point where all sockets are closed. When I run application next time I get **10048** error on **bind** call.

Because of that i decided to go through tcp connection table and kill all processes (from my previous run, however i can't see them in task manager) that use my port. I tried **GetTcpTable**, **GetTcpTable2**, **GetExtendedTcpTable**, but none of them gives me what **netstat -ano** does. My port number and id is present in **netstat -ano** output, but not in tcp table retrieved by any of those functions.

How can I get programatically **netstat -ano** data. **setsockopt** with reusable address is not a way to go, because if I connect than accept of "lost process" will be called. Please help.

```
    addrinfo hints, *result;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    //... get ip and so on

    getaddrinfo(ip, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    sock = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    bind(sock, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);  // here is error 10048
```

Another process is already listening on DEFAULT_PORT ( that process is possibly still running from my previous program test, however i can't see it in task manager), that's why error 10048 is present.

Here is code to find this process:

```
void TerminateProcOnPort2(const char* port_str)
{
    int size = 0;
    if(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetTcpTable2(NULL, (ULONG*)&size, false))
    {
        MIB_TCPTABLE2* pids = (MIB_TCPTABLE2*)malloc(size);
        if(NO_ERROR == GetTcpTable2(pids, (ULONG*)&size, false))
        {
            MIB_TCPROW2* owner;
            UINT port = atoi(port_str);

            for(UINT i = 0; i < pids->dwNumEntries; ++i)
            {
                owner = &pids->table[i];
                if(owner->dwLocalPort == port)
                {
                    printf("GOOD\n");
                    // now we can kill this process by id...
                }
            }
        }
        else PrintError("GetTcpTable 2 error");
    }
    else PrintError("GetTcpTable 1 error");
}
```

My port is not present in retrieved table, however netstat -ano sees it. Help.

Comment: Without code we cannot tell what you've tried.

Comment: Found this post where a C# application uses a wrapper over GetExtendedTcpTable to fetch information including PIDs. There is link below the article to download the interop wrapper code as well which shows the arguments being passed to GetExtendedTcpTable. http://www.timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c/

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the `ntohs()` Windows function on all numbers retrieved from `GetTcpTable` to get the same output as from netstat, e.g., `ntohs(owner->dwLocalPort)`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11227359)

Comment: I edited answer and it does provide an answer and probably correct one.  I can not commen on his question, because I do not have enough reputation for it. I cant see problem here and dont undertand why you voted for deletion.

Comment: @PCLuddite Yes, it does provide an answer to the question, even before the edits, and the answer is to use `ntohs()`, and not only is it an answer, it is a correct answer. Please read before you act.

Comment: @user207421 I reviewed this 3 years ago, and in retrospect, I made an error. A perfect example of why multiple votes are required before an answer is deleted.